# Show Every Data from Mysql Database except the last one

Tags: php, mysql, web

```
$query = "SELECT id,subject,date,notice from sam_notice ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";$result = $conn->query($query);
```

This query pulls the last one only and i can view in  section 1

```
$query2 = "SELECT id,subject,date,notice from sam_notice ORDER BY id DESC";$result2 = $conn->query($query2);
```

This query pulls all data to view in  section 2

What is the change i need in query2  so that it can pull all data except the last one?

Comment: Hi @User : You didn't responded to any of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If, column `id` is `primary key` and `auto-incremented`.

```
$query2 = "SELECT id,subject,date,notice 
           FROM sam_notice 
           WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM sam_notice)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT id,subject,date,notice 
 FROM sam_notice
WHERE id != (SELECT MAX(id) FROM sam_notice
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't look for an SQL way. Instead simply skip the 1st row (it's the last one since you used `DESC`) when using the result. Something like this:

```
$query2 = "SELECT id,subject,date,notice from sam_notice ORDER BY id DESC";
$result2 = $conn->query($query2);
$begin = TRUE;
while ($row = <some fetch method on $result2, depending on your current API>) {
  if($begin) {
    $begin = false;
    continue;
  }
  // use other rows...
}
```